# What do the astika schools believe, is story of Urvasi and Pururava mentioned in the rig veda and Satapatha Brahmana real or mythology?

Tags: vedas, story

According to astika schools, is the [story](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45336/22556) of Urvasi and  Pururava mentioned in the rig veda and in [Satapatha Brahmana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/satapatha-brahmana-english/d/doc63439.html) real history or legend or mythology .

What does scholar say about it?

Comment: Thus question is OP based. BTW this story is also mentioned in Bhagwatam

Comment: @SanatanDarshan what do the scholars say about this.

Comment: @SanatanDarshan how it is opinion based can you explain it

Comment: I think you want to change your question similar to this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45190/do-all-astika-schools-of-thought-in-hinduism-believe-that-itihaasramayan-and-ma else it will be closed as opinion-based.